12 hours transit at SFO - Things to do?
I have close to 12 hours transit at SFO, arriving at 1130am and departing (international destination) at 1120pm. What are things to do during this time? My assumptions:

It may take 1.5hours from airport to SFO downtown, which mean I will be in downtown around 1pm
I don't want to stay late evening either, so I guess better to leave to airport by 7pm?
Which leaves me 6hours approx to explore, is that sufficient to visit golden gate bridge and downtown?


1.5 hours just to get from the airport to downtown seems exaggerated, it should take way less than an hour, including getting to the the BART station, buying tickets, waiting for a train, and getting to your destination. Of course if you count the total time from aircraft door opening it may be more, but that depends a lot on the circumstances: are you arriving on a domestic or international flight? Are your two flights on the same ticket? Do you have checked bags (or large carry-ons)? What date are you travelling on?

San Francisco is actually rather small for a large US city, approximately 49 square miles or roughly a square of 7 miles on a side, due to being surrounded by water on 3 sides. Also, more than half of that is “suburban”, mostly single and multi-family housing. The area of interest to a tourist is mainly the north-eastern quarter of the city, excluding Golden-Gate Park and the SF end of the GG Bridge.
The major tourist areas include the “downtown” area mainly along Market Street (including UN Plaza), North Beach, the Embarcadero and Fisherman’s Wharf. (There are probably other areas I’m not thinking of. I live near but not in SF and I don’t visit often.) San Francisco also has good public transit so it easy to get around.
The bottom line is that in 6 hours, you can see a lot, though certainly not all of “downtown San Francisco”. I’d suggest that you do web searches for tourist guides.
By the way, BART (Bay Area Rapid Transit) has a station in the International terminal of SFO. The trains from there to SF run at least every 20 minutes for the time period you’re talking about and can have you to UN Plaza in 30 minutes.

Public transport in itself are a tourist destination to experience in SF, e.g. the F Market & Wharves line or obviously the Cable Cars.

With San Francisco being as small as it is, a reasonably fit person can also see the most interesting sights in 6 hours by just walking around after taking the BART downtown from the airport. If you do this, just be mindful to avoid the bad areas (the so-called Tenderloin) west of downtown.

The Golden Gate Bridge is a bit out of the way compared to the rest of the usual tourist destinations in San Francisco.
But fret not: the bridge is in plain view from a large number of places in San Francisco, especially Fisherman’s Wharf (which is really just a big tourist destination, but still a fun place to visit).
A few things you can do:

Take the BART from SFO to Powell Street station. Should take a bit over 30 minutes (+ time to get to the BART station + time to buy tickets, but see below + waiting time)
If you want you can visit Union Square and adjoining stores (depends a lot on your tastes)
Take the cable car. There are two lines departing from Powell Street (Powell and Hyde and Powell and Mason), which get to different (but relatively close) places on the northern shore. The most interesting one is probably Powell and Hyde (which includes a stop at the top of the famous Lombard Street). Warning: there can be huuuuuuge queues at the Cable Car stop, so you’ll probably just take the first one you can. One frequent alternative is to try to catch one a few stops uphill, but when it’s really busy they won’t stop there. Of course you can climb up to California Street on foot. If you manage to get on board one, the best spot is in front on the outside. Make sure you don’t have anything that dangles (no carry-on of course!).
From the northern shore you will see the Golden Gate Bridge
Visit local (tourist) attractions such as Ghirardelli Square, Fisherman’s Wharf. If you have the time you could even hop to Alcatraz for a tour (even better views of the Golden Gate Bridge, and the tour is worth it). Your could also visit the USS Pampanito submarine.
In Fisherman’s Wharf don’t miss the sea lions (how could you?).
From next to Fisherman’s Wharf take the F line. It’s a street car which uses only heritage trams from all over the world. Again, it can get very busy and there can be long waits, so plan for quite some extra time. Alight at Embarcadero.
Take the BART from there back to SFO.

You can do the same circuit the other way around. But remember that on busy days you will wait quite a long time for the cable car or the F line (waiting one hour or more for each one would not be unusual).
Also remember that San Francisco Bay is subject to very frequent fog, and that the weather can change drastically over the day. A very frequent pattern in the summer is that you will be roasting until about 4-5 pm, and then the fog comes in, and you’re suddenly in cold wet weather. Don’t forget to take a jacket or sweater even if it seems to be scorching hot. The Golden Gate Bridge will often disappear in the fog quite early (it can make for pretty dramatic photos if you are lucky though).
Tip: buy and load a Clipper Card on your phone before you arrive. This can be used for BART, Muni (trams and buses) and even the Cable Cars (warning: a Cable Car ride is much more expensive than a regular Muni ride). You can also buy a one day visitor pass (though I’m not sure how that works on your mobile), which will include the cable car, but won’t include BART to/from SFO.
If you have to do one thing in SF, I would say the Cable Car (especially if you can get a good spot on the outside).

Usually if you don't take a Uber, you need to take a bus to the Golden Gate Bridge from the downtown, and there are no nearby train stations around the bridge so you need to wait for the bus again when you come back. This might take some time, but for you case, it's much enough, the Bay Area Rapid Transit is very convenient and comfortable for you to shuttle between the airport and the downtown area.
